# Android - Displaying an additional layout underneath an ImageView when using Picasso's fit() and centerInside()

Tags: button, imageview, picasso

Below is an ImageView that can't 'wrap_content' on the height and width as it is displaying the image using Picasso's fit() and centerInside() attributes.

Due to this, I have to either set a height in dp or state 'match_parent'. If I set a specific height in dp my Button will display but this isn't ideal for different sizes screens of course. If I set 'match_parent' the ImageView fills the rest of the screen and I can't display my Button underneath the ImageView.

Does anyone know of a way to nest my ImageView in some way so I can display my final Button?

Also, I can't work out how to align my picture of the top of the ImageView, please help with this as well if you can.

---

main_activity.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorBackground">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    style="@style/Toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/button_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/toolbar"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_kitty"
        style="@style/Button"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/button_kitty" />

    <Space
        android:id="@+id/space"
        android:layout_width="10dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_cat"
        style="@style/Button"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/button_cat" />

</LinearLayout>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/button_layout"
    android:layout_marginBottom="17dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true" />

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/button_layout"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:indeterminate="true"
    android:visibility="invisible" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_facebook"
    style="@style/Button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/image"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:gravity="center" />
```

---

ActivityMain.java

```
@Override
public void onResponse(Call<KittyCatModel> call, Response<KittyCatModel> response) {
    KittyCatModel model = response.body();
    String url = model.getSource();
    Picasso.with(this)
            .load(url)
            .fit()
            .centerInside()
            .into(imageView, this);
}
```

---

[image: Screen shot with Layout Bounds on]

Answer (score 0):

On Picasso's github, there's a thread regarding fit() not working when an imageView has adjustViewBounds set to true.  Remove either one and see how it goes (I'm doing this from mobile, so can't test it before answering, sorry).

Here's a link to that thread:
https://github.com/square/picasso/issues/425

That thread links to another thread on Picasso's git regarding creating a custom imageView to make this work the way you want

Here's a link to that thread:
https://github.com/square/picasso/issues/457

Answer (score 0):

Had some offline assistance with this issue, answer is:

This is nothing to do with Picasso, it is just an XML issue.

The ImageView and ProgressBar needed to be in a RelativeLayout within a
LinearLayout so I could apply layout_weight=“1” to that RelativeLayout.

This allowed me to “match_parent” on my ImageView width and height so
the image fills its layout but doesn’t hide the bottom button.

Hope that helps somebody else in the future.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/color_background"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    style="@style/Toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/button_layout_generate"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/toolbar"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="12dp">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_kitty"
        style="@style/Button"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/button_kitty" />

    <Space
        android:id="@+id/space"
        android:layout_width="10dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_cat"
        style="@style/Button"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/button_cat" />

</LinearLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/image_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/button_layout_generate"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:indeterminate="true"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

</RelativeLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/button_layout_facebook"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/image"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="12dp">

    <Space
        android:id="@+id/space_left"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.5" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_facebook"
        style="@style/Button"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/image"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/button_facebook" />

    <Space
        android:id="@+id/space_right"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.5" />

</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```